# variadic templates parameter matching in std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename Return, typename... Params>
void func(std::function<Return(Params... )> x) {}

void f(double) {}

int main() {
    //func<void, double>(f); // compile error here in the variadic case
    func(std::function<void(double)>(f));
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1.
I do not understand why does the line `func<void, double>(f);` give me a compiling error

```
/Users/vlad/minimal.cpp:10:5: error: no matching function for call to 'func'
    func<void, double>(f); // compile error here in the variadic case
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/vlad/minimal.cpp:5:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (double, type-parameter-0-1...)>' against 'void (*)(double)'
void func(std::function<Return(Params... )> x) {}
     ^
1 error generated.
```

whereas if I cast the parameter `f` to a `std::function` (as in the non-commented line) it works.

2.
And the most puzzling issue is that, if I use a non-variadic version of `func` (i.e. just replace `typename...` by `typename` so in effect `func` takes a `std::function<Return(Params)>` as parameter), then the commented line in `main` works as desired. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I do not understand why does the line `func<void, double>(f);` give me a compiling error

The compiler doesn't know that you want `Params` to be *exactly* `double`, it thinks maybe you want it to deduce a pack with more elements, such as `double, int, void*, char` or `double, double, double` or some other pack of types, and it doesn't know how to deduce that from the argument `f`.

In theory there could be other specializations of `std::function` which could be constructible from `f` and which would allow the compiler to deduce a pack of more than one type for `Params` (it can't know that isn't true without instantiating *every possible* specialization of `std::function` and testing them, which is not feasible.

> whereas if I cast the parameter `f` to a `std::function` (as in the non-commented line) it works.

Because now the compiler is able to deduce `Params` correctly.

> And the most puzzling issue is that, if I use a non-variadic version of `func` [...] then the commented line in main works as desired. Any ideas why?

Because now the compiler knows that `Params` is a single type, not a pack of zero or more types, so when you say `func<void, double>` it knows `Params` is `double`, and not `double, int, void*, char` or some other parameter pack.

**Edit** in answer to your comment, consider this:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
int func(T t, U u, V v)
{ return 0; }

int i = func<int, char>(1, '2', "three");
```

I've only given an explicit template argument for two of the parameters, so the third must still be deduced.

When you have a variadic template there could be **any number** of other parameters remaining to be deduced.

Comment: But I am passing explicitly the parameters in the instantiation `func<void, double>`, so I tell the compiler that `Return=void` and `Params...=double` (nothing more, nothing less), isn't it so? I don't get why is the complier "confused"?

Comment: No, it's not necessary to give an explicit template argument for every parameter, so `func<void, double>` only says the first two arguments are `void` and `double`, it doesn't say there are no more arguments.