# Member Variable Pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, wrapper, member-pointers, mem-fun

For a given struct:

```
struct foo
{
    void fooFunc(){}
    int fooVar = 0;
};
```

I can create a call wapper to the function: `std::mem_fn( &foo::fooFunc )` such that I can pass it into another method and call it on an object.
I want to know if there is a similar call wrapper but for member variables.

For example I'm using a pointer to a member variable here and but I'd like to use an call wrapper:

```
void bar( std::function< void( foo ) > funcPtr, int foo::* varPtr )
{
    foo myFoo;
    funcPtr( myFoo );
    foo.*varPtr = 13;
}
```

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery I actually already looked through [C++: Pointer to class data member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member) there is no STL construct.

Comment: A member variable pointer is not "C style".

Comment: Nothing in your question is from the "[STL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info)"

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @aschepler that seemed like the clearest way to delineate between an STL pointer wrapper and a simple pointer. If you feel there is a better way to state it, please edit the question.

Comment: C doesn't support pointers to members, so referring to one as C style definitely isn't the clearest way to say it! The terms you want are "call wrapper" for what `mem_fn` returns, and "pointer-to-member" for `int foo::*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N.B. Nothing in your question is from the STL (which is a library from the 1990s), `std::function` and `std::mem_fn` are part of the C++ Standard Library, which is not the same thing.

`std::mem_fn` supports member functions and member variables, so you can just do this to access the member variable and set it:

```
foo f;
std::function<int&(foo&)> var( std::mem_fn( &foo::fooVar ) );
var(f) = 1;
```

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library "functional" is definitely part of the STL.

Comment: @isarandi, but `std::function` and `std::mem_fn` are **not**, they are new in C++11 and came from Boost, not from the STL. Just because they're in the same header as something else doesn't make them the same.

Comment: But that's just a new version of the STL, right? STL is a part of the C++ Standard Library. And `std::function` is in the STL part of the C++11 Standard Library. At least that's how Wikipedia treats it. Where it came from has no relevance on where it is now.

Comment: No, that's not correct, and it's not what Wikipedia says. Parts of the STL were incorporated into the C++ Standard Library (but not all of it) and other things have gone into the C++ Standard Library later. Those other things don't become part of the STL though. `std::function` and `std::mem_fn` are not part of http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ for example.

Comment: @JonathanWakely To get into the bowels of my question, I'm trying to create a templatized setter, but doing this doesn't work: `template< typename T > void bar( std::function< T&( foo& ) > )` when called with something like `bar( std::mem_fn( &foo::fooVar ) )`. Is the problem the function pointer decay perhaps?

Comment: @JonathanMee, your second edit was not necessary, the code was valid anyway (if it didn't compile you need a better compiler)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yeah, I'm running VS2012, so I may be bit outta date. In my above comment, I asked about passing the result to a templatized function, maybe the problem is again my compiler?

Comment: No, the problem is you can't deduce `T` from the argument. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23900128/981959 which is similar. You can't deduce the `T` in `std::function<T&(foo&)>` from something which is not a `std::function<T&(foo&)>`, because the set of possible conversions that might allow deduction to succeed is infinite, and  the compiler can't handle infinity (which is not a problem with your compiler this time, my compiler can't handle infinity either :-)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to member functions, `std::mem_fn` can wrap data members too, and allow read access to them. So the following works:

```
void print_fooVar(foo& f, std::function<int(foo)> varAccess)
{
    std::cout << varAccess(f) << std::endl;
}

foo f;
print_fooVar(f, std::mem_fn(&foo::fooVar)); // prints 0
```

As JonathanWakely mentions in the comments, you can use the (unspecified) type returned by `mem_fn` itself to set the data member.

```
foo f;
std::mem_fn(&foo::fooVar)(f) = 13;
```

Or to transform it into an `std::function` use

```
void bar( foo& f, std::function<int&(foo&)> fooVarSet )
{
    fooVarSet(f) = 26;
}
```

If all you're looking for is a way to generate a callable to set the `fooVar` data member, and not using `std::mem_fn` specifically to do this, you can get the job done using a lambda expression as well.

```
void bar( foo& f, std::function<void(foo)> funcPtr, 
                  std::function<void(foo&, int)> fooVarSet )
{
    funcPtr( f );
    fooVarSet(f, 13);
}

foo f;
bar(f, std::mem_fn(&foo::fooFunc), [](foo& f, int i) {f.fooVar = i;});
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ad2029f18b01026)

Comment: `mem_fn` on a member variable returns a reference, so you can just to `mem_fn(&foo::fooVar)(f) = 1;`

Comment: @JonathanWakely It does, and I should've been clearer in the answer. What I don't know how to do is transform whatever type `mem_fn` returns into an `std::function` that can then be used to set the data member. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Oh, that's easy, just store it in a `std::function<int&(foo&)>`

Comment: @JonathanWakely I tried `std::function<int&(foo)>` and it didn't work. So close! Thanks for the pointers.