# Visual studio error when relaying variadic template parameters

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2015, variadic-templates

I have a template function with a variable number of template parameters, which are 'relayed' to a std::function parameter:

```
template<typename... Args>
    void test1(const std::function<void(Args...)> &function)
{}

static void t(float) {}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    test1<float>(nullptr);
    test1<float>(&t);
    test1<float>([](float f) -> void {

    });
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This compiles and runs fine, but visual studio underlines **all** of the *test1*-calls in *main* in red, with this error message:

```
template<class... Args> void test1(const std::function<void(Args...)> &function)

no instance of function template "test1" matches the argument list
    argument types are: (lambda []void(float f)->void)
```

This, on the other hand, does not show as error:

```
template<typename... Args>
    void test2(Args... a)
{}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    test2<float>(1.f);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Am I doing something incorrectly for the first case or is this a false positive? This is just an error from visual studio itself, the compiler doesn't even throw any warnings.

// Edit:

I just did some tests on Linux with g++-5, and it doesn't let me compile the code at all:

```
root@******:/var/projects# g++-5 -std=c++1y test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:12:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘test1(std::nullptr_t)’
  test1<float>(nullptr);
                      ^
test.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: template<class ... Args> void test1(const std::function<void(Args ...)>&)
  void test1(const std::function<void(Args...)> &function)
       ^
test.cpp:5:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:12:22: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::function<void(Args ...)>’ and ‘std::nullptr_t’
  test1<float>(nullptr);
                      ^
test.cpp:13:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘test1(void (*)(float))’
  test1<float>(&t);
                 ^
test.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: template<class ... Args> void test1(const std::function<void(Args ...)>&)
  void test1(const std::function<void(Args...)> &function)
       ^
test.cpp:5:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:13:17: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::function<void(Args ...)>’ and ‘void (*)(float)’
  test1<float>(&t);
                 ^
test.cpp:16:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘test1(main(int, char**)::<lambda(float)>)’
  });
   ^
test.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: template<class ... Args> void test1(const std::function<void(Args ...)>&)
  void test1(const std::function<void(Args...)> &function)
       ^
test.cpp:5:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:16:3: note:   ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda(float)>’ is not derived from ‘const std::function<void(Args ...)>’
  });
   ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To workaround the problem and make program work as you expect you could wrap your test function in a template struct:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct foo {
   static void test1(const std::function<void(Args...)> &function) {}
};
```

And call it:

```
foo<float>::test1(nullptr);
foo<float>::test1(&t);
foo<float>::test1([](float f) -> void {

});
```

It will definitely prevent your `Args...` from being deduced.

Answer (score 1):

The visual studio parsing is a bit behind the compiler, and separately implemented. Variadic templates are still quite new to visual studio, so it's likely a known limitation/bug.

Update:

It's not clear to me what's going on even with the latest version of clang: 
[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ayb0ZpE7OAOUvU24) because you did fix `Args...` to ``float` but the corresponding non-template code does compile.

Also, if you change `Args...` to `Args` it does work. Not clear to me why...

Update 2: I found out that your question is a duplicate, with a good answer:
[variadic templates parameter matching in std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900059/variadic-templates-parameter-matching-in-stdfunction)

Sloppy summary: When you write `test2<float>` it more or less means `test2<float,Args...>`, which hinders further conversions.

Comment: Looks like it's not just limited to visual studio (See my edit).